# PRISMA, WHERE-contain clause for array of enums

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, backend, prisma

So here's my prisma schema:

```
model User {
  id                         String    @id @default(uuid())
  email                      String    @unique
  mailing_address            String
  password                   String
  verification_token         String?
  verification_token_expires DateTime?
  reset_password_token       String?
  reset_password_expires     DateTime?
  name                       String?
  roles                      Role[]
  last_auth_change           DateTime  @default(now())
}

enum Role {
  SUPER_ADMIN
  ADMIN
  USER
  EMAIL_VERIFIED
  UNVERIFIED
}
```

and i want to notify all the super admins when a user verify his email

the sql query for it is :
`'SELECT "id", "mailing_address", "roles" FROM "User" WHERE "roles" @> ARRAY[\'SUPER_ADMIN\']::"Role"[] ;'`
but i couldn't figure out how to do it with PRISMA , because when i want to write something in the where clause for roles in Prisma, the only option is `equal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's an open request [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3475) so `equals` is the only available argument.

As a workaround, you can use a [raw query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/raw-database-access) as above via `prisma.$queryRaw`.

Comment: right now I'm doing exact same thing with that SQL query i have

i was just wondering how to do it with PRISMA, thnx for the infoon the open request thing though